# C# LINQ - Center a distribution around zero

Tags: c#, linq

Apologies, due to my poor understanding of the question, please find below a redrafted question.

Using C# LINQ, is it possible to return the distribution of dataset **and center the distribution around zero**?

Please find below code which returns the cumulative density function (cdf) based on an input dataSet.  In the resulting cdf, the percentile represents the middle of the "bucket" (as opposed to the top or bottom border of the "bucket"). This means when dataSet contains:

- an odd number of elements {1,2,3,4,5}, the percentile 0.5 will occur at the
  center value.[image: odd]
- an even number of elements {1,2,3,4}, the percentile 0.5 can be
  interpolated between the two center values (upper and lower).

[image: even]

Code:

```
void Main()
{
    var dataSet = new List<double> {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3};
    var dist = new Distribution(dataSet);
    dist.Cdf.Dump();
}

public class Distribution
{
   public int Count { get; set; }
   public double Max { get; set; }
   public double Min { get; set; }
   public IOrderedEnumerable<VP> Cdf { get; set; }

   public Distribution(IEnumerable<double> series)
   {
       Count = series.Count();
       Max = series.Max();
       Min = series.Min();
       Cdf = Populate(series);
   }

   private IOrderedEnumerable<VP> Populate(IEnumerable<double> source)
   {
       return source.AsParallel().ToLookup(k => k, k => source.Where(n => n < k))
           .Select(k => new VP
           {
               Value = k.Key,
               Percentile = Percentile(source, k)
           })
           .OrderBy(k => k.Value);
   }

   private double Percentile(IEnumerable<double> source, IGrouping<double, IEnumerable<double>> k)
   {
       return (k.First().Count() + 0.5 * k.Count()) / source.Count();
   }
}

public struct VP
{
    public double Value;
    public double Percentile;
}
```

The above code returns the distribution:

[image: Actual]

With an odd number of elements, it shows the 0.5 percentile at the center, which is correct.   However, in this case I am trying to center the distribution around zero, so:

- negative values are less than 0.5,
- zero occurs at 0.5, and
- positive are greater than 0.5.

Is it possible?  Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Percentrank` method suffers from the problem that it computes `Min` and `Max` **three** times for each value in your array. And to compute `Min` or `Max` all elements in the array has to be inspected. For 12 elements you will iterate the array 3 x 12 + 1 = 37 times (including the main `Select` loop) which will still be fast but as your input array grows it may start to incur a cost.

It is much more efficient to iterate the array once to compute both values at the same time:

```
var dataSet = new[] { -5D, -4D, -3D, -2D, 0D, 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, 4D };
var seed = new { Min = Double.PositiveInfinity, Max = Double.NegativeInfinity };
var aggregate = dataSet.Aggregate(
  seed,
  (a, value) => new {
    Min = Math.Min(a.Min, value),
    Max = Math.Max(a.Max, value)
  }
);
```

You can also sum and count the input here if you need the mean and similar summary values.

You can then compute the desired distribution (notice that you need to treat 0 as a special case):

```
var distribution = dataSet.Select(
  value => new {
    Value = value,
    Proportion = value >= 0D
      ? 0.5D*value/aggregate.Max + 0.5D
      : -0.5D*value/aggregate.Min + 0.5D
  }
);
```

The desired result:

```
 Value | Proportion
-------+------------
    -5 |     0
    -4 |     0.1
    -3 |     0.2
    -2 |     0.3
     0 |     0.5
     1 |     0.625
     2 |     0.75
     3 |     0.875
     4 |     1
     4 |     1
```

I skipped the requirements about "using LINQ" and "suggesting code for `Main`" because these requirements were unclear to me. However, I did use LINQ and you only have a "main" body in this solution so I hope you find it useful.

Comment: In your example code which iterates the array once and computes both Min and Max, how would you include a calculation for **Count**?

Comment: @shansen: Add a third property to the anonymous type named `Count`. Initialize it to 0 when creating `seed` and in the aggregating lambda add a line to increment the count: `Count = a.Count + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, the question is unclear to me, but this gives the result you are showing:

```
public double Percentrank(double[] array, double x)
{
    if(x >= 0)
        return x / array.Max() / 2 + 0.5;
    else
        return -(x / array.Min() / 2 - 0.5);    
}
```

It's just normalizing (0 to 0.5, instead of 0 to 1) two distinct distributions: one for positives and one for negatives. Is that what you are expecting?

#### Update

In the comments it seems you want this inlined, instead of on the `Percentrank` function. This should do:

```
var vp = sequence.Select(value => new VP
{
    Value = value,
    Proportion = value >= 0 
                   ? value / sequence.Max() / 2 + 0.5 
                   : -(value / sequence.Min() / 2 - 0.5)
});
```

Comment: It does solve the problem as posed.  Is is possible to do this not in the PercentRank method by in the body of Main()?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var vp = sequence.Select(value => new VP
{
    Value = value,
    Proportion = value >= 0?  value  / sequence.Max() / 2 + 0.5 :-(value  / sequence.Min() / 2 - 0.5)
});
```